# Should I master any class?

Tags: tribes-ascend

Do I get anything from mastering in a class? Or should I just find a good loadout and get xp by playing more? Is there something like challenges, where if you master a weapon you get like 1000xp?

Comment: You should clarify if you mean "should I pay a bunch of XP to immediately master a class", or "should I put effort into mastering a class' equipment".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no extra hidden bonuses or rewards for fully unlocking a class, other than whatever the individual upgrades provide. However, it's a good idea to max out anything that you actually plan on using.

You can earn [Badges](http://tribes.wikia.com/wiki/Badges) (like achievements), which provide one-time XP bonuses, but these are awarded through gameplay, not completing upgrades.

Comment: I wish they add challenges and one time xp bonuses for mastering weapons. could be a way to get xp faster.

Comment: Getting XP faster without paying for it isn't really in the business model.

Comment: And that is the issue with Free to Pay games, they often become Pay to Win

Comment: @GarethJones: Compared to a lot of other F2P games, Tribes: Ascend is *definitely* not Pay To Win.

Comment: I dont know, cause I havnt played it, however ive seen it in other F2P games

Answer (score 0):

I find the best thing to master is the armor of a class, since you get far more upgrades for the 15k exp, and they are very useful on lighter classes that have low HP to begin with.